# Error en el año usando datetimepicker de bootstrap

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, bootstrap, asp.net-mvc

estoy usando datetimepicker de bootstrap para el campo fecha de nacimiento de un formulario. El problema viene cuando insertamos el año manualmente, es decir, en ves de usar el calendario, introduzco la fecha por teclado de la siguiente manera, "251192" el mismo lo transforma en 25-11-1992 todo correcto porque ese es el formato que tengo pero, cuando el año es menor a "69" es decir, "251168" me lo transforma en 25-11-2068, he estado buscando el ¿por qué? me genera esto pero no logro dar con la respuesta. agradecería mucho su apoyo para solventar este problema.

de antemano muchas gracias.

El campo en mi HTML

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group">
               <div class='input-group date' id='myDatepicker2'>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(d => d.FechaNacimiento, "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = @Html.DisplayNameFor(d => d.FechaNacimiento) })
                     <span class="input-group-addon">
                           <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                     </span>
</div>
                                


<script>
        $(function () {
            $('#myDatepicker2').datetimepicker({
                format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
            });
        });
    </script>
```

este es mi modelo:

```
[Required]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = {0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
[Display(Name = "FechaNacimiento")]
public Nullable<DateTime> FechaNacimiento {get;set;}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en español. Sería excelente si pudieras adjuntar un [ejemplo mínimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) del código en la pregunta. Para familiarizarte con el sitio, puedes leer ["Cómo preguntar"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) y hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender cómo funciona.

Comment: No lo pongo como respuesta porque no puedo probar la opción, pero ¿serviría agregar la opción [`assumeNearbyYear`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#assumenearbyyear)?

Comment: aunque añada la siguiente línea assumeNearbyYear: true
no soluciona el problema

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo con la documentación, la opción [startDate](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#startdate) define la fecha más antigua a ser permitida.

De modo que para cambiar ese valor (que asumo sin saberlo que por defecto debe ser 1970-01-01) deberías declarar tu datepicker con la opción startDate así:

```
$('.miclase').datepicker({
    startDate: '01/01/1900',
    endDate: '01/01/2099'
});
```

Comment: asi declaro mi datepicker
$(function () {
            $('#myDatepicker2').datetimepicker({
                format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
            });
        });
añadiendo lo que mencionas
startDate: '01/01/1900',
endDate: '01/01/2099'

no transforma mi input de 251150 => 25-11-1950 o en su defecto como hacia antes 25-11-2050. me arroja error de formato ya que debe recibirlo DD-MM-YYYY

Comment: Claro algo así te quedaría: `$(function () { $('#myDatepicker2').datetimepicker({ format: 'DD-MM-YYYY', startDate: '01/01/1900' }); });`

Comment: lo que quiero decir es que no funciona, no actualiza la fecha y tampoco soluciona el error del año

Comment: ¿puedes mostrar más código? es difícil ayudarte si no sabemos lo que escribiste.

Comment: ya actualice mi pregunta